# Office File Converter (ofc.exe) Timeout

Tags: ms-office, office-2007, ofc

We're running into an issue with OFC successfully converting an excel file. We've tweaked the 
ofc.ini file to change the following:

```
LogDestinationPath=C:\src\tools
```

The folders to convert to:

```
fldr=C:\src\Tools\temp
```

The interesting thing is that this conversion works fine on two of our development machines but not the 3rd or on the server. Here is the output from the command prompt on the server (running as administrator).

```
C:\temp\Tools>ofc.exe
Microsoft Office File Converter version 12.0.4518.1032
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Automatically converts Office documents to 2007 Microsoft Office system file for
mat based on settings in the OFC.INI control file.

Converting files from folder C:\temp\Tools\excel
Converting: C:\temp\Tools\excel\TestReport.xls Writing converted file to: C:\tem
p\Tools\Converted\excel\TestReport.xlsx
Error: C:\temp\Tools\excel\TestReport.xls failed to convert
Start:  2013-04-30 16:54:52
End:    2013-04-30 16:55:06
Total time used to convert files (sec): 14
Total number of files processed: 1
Total number of files converted: 0
Conversion Complete.
```

Any thoughts as to why this would fail intermittently?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the `timeout` option - it may be that your server is less than ressouces - apparently the file is big more you need to increase the `timeout` - in `ofc.ini` :

```
[Run]
LogDestinationPath=C:\src\tools

TimeOut = 10000

[ConversionOptions]
```